# 15 operators on duty, and on average 14 are simultaneously busy. What is the probability that all operators are busy?

Tags: probability

The suggestion is to use Poisson distribution, but I want to know why the following approach does not work: I reason that for a particular operator, the probability that they are busy is $\frac{14}{15}$, so the probability of all 15 operators being busy is $(\frac{14}{15})^{15}$.

Comment: Can you clarify the suggestion to use Poisson? It looks like you need some distribution for the operators' service time.